# Search nested Array in UISearchbar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to search an array of nested items where enters a text and it searches both the team and user array and returns an object. I am able to search team but not able to search user nested array.

Here is my code

```
// Array
let searchArray = [MyTeam]()

// Search
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
searchArray = searchArray.filter { ($0.name.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil || ($0.users.filter{($0.name.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }) ) }
}

// Model
struct MyTeam: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let users: [MyUser]
}
struct MyUser: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `filter` on the users array here

```swift
$0.users.filter {($0.name.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

You can use `contains` method which will return a `Bool`

```swift
$0.users.contains { $0.name.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

So the final function would look like this. Also I think you need to use `searchText` instead of `searchString`

```swift
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchArray = searchArray.filter { team in
        team.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            || team.users.contains { user in
                user.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            }
    }
}
```